# figma to reactjs: Is it possible or do it manually

Tags: reactjs, figma

I have some figma designs. I want to convert them to reactjs material ui. I searched a lot. But didnt find a proper way to do this.

So is it possible or not

If possible how much effective is the result.

Comment: There is no way

Comment: Then figma is for more representation. To know the dimension etc and navigation

Comment: Figma is a design tool.